# WebView cause long delay when WebView.setBlockNetworkImage is activated

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

Now I'm developing kinds of WebView application.
In some situation, I don't need loading image on the WebView, then I invoke WebView.setBlockNetworkImage(true) dynamically.

The API works fine as I want, but in some case, long delay cause before starting load to the next page when I tap a link tag.

Let me show you the minimum code for the reproduction as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG="MainActivity";
private WebView mWebView;
private WebSettings mWebSettings;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    mWebSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    mWebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebSettings.setBlockNetworkImage(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    mWebView.loadUrl( "http://www.yahoo.co.jp");
}
```

When I run the code above, the app will load Yahoo! Japan page. Next you click the auction page link ( you will see the hammer icon), the WebView will wait for seconds before starting load. Delay is 5 sec or so on.
If we provide false to setBlockNetworkImage(), loading will start immediately.

[Link button on Yahoo! Japan page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Iwse.png)

I confirmed the same behavior on API22 with emulator, and API23 with the real device.
The link button in the contents is a just 'A tag'. But for now I don't see the same behavior on any other site.

I don't understand if blocking image resource is related to the delay on  clicking a tag.
If you have a clue or solution, please let me know.

Comment: As this is the minimal example i understand that javascript has to be enabled?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The reason why I enabled JS is to keep the contents as it is required. ( When JS is disabled, the contents warn to enable JS.)
However when I checked it with JS disabled, loading started immediately. It may affect the behavior.